# como hacer este tipo de letra?

Tags: html, css, fuentes

quiero obtener este tipo de letra

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

estuve intentando pero no se que tipo es

```css
@font-face {
       font-family: "Kimberley";
       src: url(http://www.princexml.com/fonts/larabie/ »
       kimberle.ttf) format("truetype");
     }
     h1 { font-family: "Kimberley", sans-serif }
```

```html
<h1>Reinventamos 
el trabajo en equipo</h1>
```

Comment: Esto es un problema tipográfico. El nombre tiene puesto ` » kimberle.ttf`, si se le quita el ` »` y se deja sólo en `kimberle.ttf`ya funciona (si no se ve bien en la solución de Luis Andrés es porque hace falta poner https para los snippets).

Answer (score 1):

Por lo que puedo observar estas defininiendo de forma incorrecta tu archivo css, anexo un ejemplo de como deberías escribirlo.

```
@font-face {
font-family: TravelingTypewriter;
src: url(TravelingTypewriter.ttf);
}
```

Posteriormente ya la utilizas

```
p {
font-family: Gentium, serif;
}
```

```css
@font-face {
font-family: Kimberley;
src: url(http://www.princexml.com/fonts/larabie/kimberle.ttf) format("truetype");
}

h1 { font-family: Kimberley }
```

```html
<h1>Reinventamos 
el trabajo en equipo</h1>
```

Comment: Debieras señalar que, específicamente, está mal escrita la url de la tipografía

Comment: Si, es lo que note después de revisar su código a detalle, sin embargo creo que su pregunta se orienta más a que no sabe como se llama la fuente, por tanto esta demás poner el código.

De cualquier forma gracias por tu comentario, lo tomaré en cuenta, solo quería ser más especifico